# Trying to run Python script with launchctl / launchd but it won't load. Exit status is 2

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to run a simple Python script through launchctl every 5 minutes on macOS. I've created my playlist as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.myscript</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>/Users/me/Documents/myscript.py</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>300</integer>
    </dict>
  </plist>
```

However, the script never runs. I've loaded and unloaded it multiple times. Executing the command

```
/Users/me/Documents/myscript.py
```

works just fine, since I added '#!/usr/bin/env python' to the beginning of the Python script. If I run launchctl -l, I see:

```
    -     2   com.myscript
```

I'm not sure what an exit status of 2 means. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using cron (which previously wasn't working either) and moving the script in question to the root of my Home folder instead of the Documents folder. I think the issue is macOS Catalina's new restrictions on access to files in the Documents or Desktop folders. Moving the script elsewhere seems to resolve it.